# How to better handle reusable compose component with error handling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a process where when users want to change password, they are able to do that within a current password, new password, retypenewpassword flow. My challenge however has been with using my reusable outlined text field to handle the error. For example if the users enters an old password and it is wrong it shows below the outlinedTextField that wrong password was entered. Like the image I have attached

The challenge I experienced with Jetpack Compose is on the `isError,` for all 3 since I am using one but customizing output for each. I can not add my condition there to validate the `error`. Or maybe I am approaching this the wrong way. Here is my composable.

```
@Composable
fun UserInputTextField(
    fieldState: String,
    onFieldChange: (String) -> Unit,
    label: String,
    isError: Boolean = false
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField(
        value = fieldState, onValueChange = {
            onFieldChange(it)
        },
        isError = isError
        label = { androidx.compose.material.Text(text = label) },
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 16.dp)
           ,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Blue,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black
        )
    )
}
```

Now when I call my reusable, I want for all my three OutlinedEditText when there is an error display something like the image [image]

My problem is, how can I display an error on all 3 `UserInputTextField` using the isError since the message has to be under the OutlinedTextField.

```
UserInputTextField(
                    fieldState = usernameState.value,
                    onFieldChange = { usernameState.value = it },
                    label = "Enter Name",
                    isError = if(state.usernameState.isValidPassword)... do something else print error?
        

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want, but I think that you just want to put a label under the `OutlinedTextField`.

Unfortunately, the Google composable doesn't have this attribute, but you can add it yourself.

If that is your case, you can add a `Column` around your `OutlineTextField` and add under a `Text` composable and style it. So you can add `supportingLabel` parameter for your `UserInputTextField`.

```
@Composable
fun UserInputTextField(
    fieldState: String,
    onFieldChange: (String) -> Unit,
    label: String,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    supportingLabel: String? = null,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    androidx.compose.material.Column { 
        androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField(
            value = fieldState, onValueChange = {
                onFieldChange(it)
            },
            isError = isError
            label = { Text(text = label) },
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 16.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Color.Blue,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black
            )
        )
        androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = supportingLabel != null && isError
        ) {
            androidx.compose.material.Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp),
                text = supportingLabel,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
                color = Color.Red
            )
         }
    }
}
```